# Passing a variable from a listview to another activity

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have been struggling using some tutorial for passing a listview option to a new activity and make it the title (I will do other stuff with it later). I have set up a OnClickListener by what is best to put inside it

```
ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sportslist);

String[] items = { "Archery", "Badminton", "Cricket", "Dodgeball", "Equestrian", "Football", "Golf", "Handball", "Ice Hockey", "Ju Jitsu", "Karate", "Lacrosse", "Mountain Biking", "Netball" };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 

    ?????

}
});
```

Thanks

EDIT:Extra code

```
final TextView changetitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailedsocietyname);
changetitle.setText(name);
```

Comment: Could you post the logcat that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For of all you will need to get the item that was selected:

```
final String selected = items[position];
```

Or as doctoror drive has suggested

```
final String selected = (String) parent.getSelectedItem();
```

Then you will need to pass that string as an extra to your new activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyClass.class);
i.putExtra("name", selected);
startActivity (i);
```

And then finally in your next activity

```
    Intent in = getIntent();
    String name = in.getStringExtra(("name"));//gets name from intent
```

Comment: Or better: final String selected = (String) parent.getSelectedItem();

Comment: thanks a lot, but its giving me an error due to the 'parent' of the code Doctoror Drive gave... I know this is example code, but what does 'parent' represent

Comment: I think I had it in the wrong place aha. I have a stop working error now, about to check logcat

Comment: @jcw When I try to use the 'name' variable for something the app shuts down. I am trying to use it to change the title using.. I'll put the extra code in the question actually

Answer (score 0):

in `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)` add this code.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextClass.class);
i.putExtra("selectedItem", items[position]);
startActivity (i);
```

for getting value in NextClass Activitiy :

```
String SelectedItem = getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedItem");
```

Answer (score 0):

public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,int position, long id)

```
String str = items[position];
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextClass.class);
in.putExtra("itemkey", str);
startActivity (in);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to you Activity where you have `listview`

following is the `variable` that will contain the `value` that you want to pass to `other activity`

Declare it before `Oncreate` statement

```
// Activity_1

public final static String send_to_other_activity="ListViewSelected_ID";
```

Add the following code to the `listView1.setOnItemClickListener`

```
Intent i= new Intent(Recipe_List.this,Recipe_View.class);
i.putExtra(send_to_other_activity, string.valueof(position));
// itz (key-value) pair on the left key thru which u will access it on other place. on the right value that you want to pass
// Iam passing posiion to other activity here
startActivity(i);
```

Now on other `activity` extract this value from the `key` by adding following statement to the oonCreate of other activity

```
//Activity_2

getdata_from_list =getIntent().getStringExtra(Activity_1.send_to_other_activity);
```

now you have teh desired value in `getdata_from_list`